# Instance read Haskell

Tags: haskell, instance

I need to implement a read instance of the data type

```
data GameAction = GameAction (Int, Int) deriving (Eq)
```

I did this

```
instance Read GameAction where
  readProc (x:xs:_) = setGA (read x) (read xs)
```

But i get the error

```
`readProc' is not a (visible) method of class `Read'
```

any idea??

Comment: What's unclear about the error?

Comment: how to fix it, i coudn't implement this instance properly

Comment: 1. Read the error message.  2. Understand the error message.  3. Fix the error.

Comment: `readProc` is not a method of the `Read` typeclass. Perhaps you meant to use `readsPrec` or `readPrec`? See the Prelude documentation for more information on how to implement `Read`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, try to include more information and context in your question next time as it's helpful.

Second, it appears as if your issue is simply a typo: `readProc` vs. the actual `readPrec` method in the `Read` typeclass.

Third, implementing `Read` is not neccesary here as it can be easily derived:

```
data GameAction = GameAction (Int, Int) deriving (Show,Eq,Read)
```

And in ghci:

```
ghci> let x = GameAction (5,6)
ghci> (read . show) x == id x
True
```

So there you go.

But more importantly, why are you trying to implement a `Read` instance by hand? `Show` and `Read` are for encoding/decoding data types to and from `String`, which should only be used for debug purposes. If you want something more specialized than what the automatically derived `Read` instance gives you, you're probably looking for something more than what `Read` should be used for. If you want to parse UTF-8 strings into data types, look at combining the `text` library with the `attoparsec` library.

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful i am new in stack overflow, for the next time i will try to include more info about de issue.

I need to implement the read because is for a homework task from functional programming (we are supposed to do a game, strategic tic tac toe).

Answer (score 3):

Thanks you all.

I could solve my problem like follow

```
instance Read GameAction where
readsPrec _ (x:y:rest) = let board = read [x] :: Int;
                       cel = read [y] :: Int;
                       in
                       if all isDigit [x,y] then
                        [(setGA board cel, rest)]
                       else []
readsPrec _ _ = []
```